# Configurar modal com bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Estou com um modal utilizo bootstrap, porém quando coloco dentro de uma div para formatar o tamanho, ele me aparece estranho.
Segue o modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalTransportador" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Transportador</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label asp-for="TransportadorID" class="col-md-6 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="text" asp-for="TransportadorID" onkeypress="return BuscaDados1(event);" onblur="CarregaFornecedor1(this.value);" class="form-control" name="TransportadorID" id="idtransportador" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1"> <th href="#" style="text-align:right"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalPesquisaFornecedor" title="Pesquisar Transportador" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-search fa-lg"></i></a></th></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label class="control-label" id="fornecedor1"></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label class="control-label" name="NomeTransportador" id="nomefornecedor1" ></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label class="control-label" name="EnderecoTransportador" id="ruafornecedor1"></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label class="control-label" name="CidadeTransportador" id="cidadefornecedor1"></label>
                            <label class="control-label" id="espaco"></label>
                            <label class="control-label" name="EstadoTransportador" id="estadofornecedor"></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label class="control-label" name="DocumentoTransportador" id="documentofornecedor"></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label class="control-label" name="InscEstadualTransportador" id="inscricaoestadual"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12"><br /></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Concluir</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele fica dessa forma, com essa linha no meio, quando uso `class="col-md-12"` como posso corrigir ?

Comment: Qual versão do Bootstrap?

Comment: Versão `Bootstrap v3.3.7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira de se ajustar isto é colocando uma `div class="row"` depois dos **form-group**:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalTransportador">Modal</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModalTransportador" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
             <h4 class="modal-title">Transportador</h4>
          </div>
                 
          <div class="form-group">
             <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                   <label asp-for="TransportadorID" class="col-md-6 control-label">fgfgf</label>
                   <div class="col-md-5">
                      <input type="text" asp-for="TransportadorID" onkeypress="return BuscaDados1(event);" onblur="CarregaFornecedor1(this.value);" class="form-control" name="TransportadorID" id="idtransportador" />
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-md-1"> <th href="#" style="text-align:right"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalPesquisaFornecedor" title="Pesquisar Transportador" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-search fa-lg">g</i></a></th></div>
                </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label class="control-label" id="fornecedor1"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label class="control-label" name="NomeTransportador" id="nomefornecedor1">Label</label>
                    </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                             <label class="control-label" name="EnderecoTransportador" id="ruafornecedor1">Label</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                             <label class="control-label" name="CidadeTransportador" id="cidadefornecedor1">Label</label>
                             <label class="control-label" id="espaco">vbv</label>
                             <label class="control-label" name="EstadoTransportador" id="estadofornecedor">Label</label>
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-md-12">
                             <label class="control-label" name="DocumentoTransportador" id="documentofornecedor">Label</label>
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-md-12">
                             <label class="control-label" name="InscEstadualTransportador" id="inscricaoestadual">Label</label>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12"><br /></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Concluir</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

O que me parece estar a acontecer e que estás a mostrar o html.
E provavelmente o que pretendes é que apareça quando queres mostrar a mensagem ao utilizador.
Tenta colocar isto no teu div

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

A parte relevante e aria-hidden="true"
caso queiras manter visivel nao necessitas disso.
O que reparei também é que essas linhas é onde deveria estar o conteudo do teu modal.
Provavelmente tens alguma tag fora do sítio.
Também verifiquei agora que nao tens um `<div class="modal-body">` , tenta colocar tudo dentro do body e verifica se já encaixa tudo direitinho
Caso nao funcione e te possa ajudar em algo mais avisa!

Comment: Tiago, continua da mesma forma, creio que o problema esteja nas divs `col-md-12` porque quando eu tiro todas elas, fica tudo certo.

Comment: Também verifiquei agora que nao tens um `<div class="modal-body">` , tenta colocar tudo dentro do body e verifica se já encaixa tudo direitinho